# Conditionally returning part of a line

Tags: matlab

I am fairly new to matlab and I would need some help with extracting data from a XML file. I need to cycle through lines - know I can do this with

```
tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    disp(tline)
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end
```

and then I need to obtain the variable 'Y' from line:

```
<X>'Y'<Z> if X==something
```

which I don't know how. Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather use `xmlread` instead of trying to parse the xml yourself.
E.g. like this:

```
doc = xmlread(xmlfilename);
% get the `<X>` elements:
elems = doc.getElementsByTagName('X');
% return its text-content:
text = char(elems.item(0).getTextContent())
```

(Got no matlab here, may contain typos...)

Comment: I've been having issues with `xmlread`, trying to solve them here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887745/xmlread-parsing-issues), feel free to help :)